# Is there a shorthand for repeated reassignment of a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the example:

```
x = 27
x = sqr(x)
x += 2
x = x * 0.1
```

This could trivially be reduced to

```
x = 0.1 * (sqr(27) + 2)
```

Now, consider (x as an OrderedDict)

```
x = {k: bubble_sort(v) for k, v in x.items()}

x = {k: rename(k) for k, v in x.items()}

x = {k: abs(k) for k, v in x.items()}
```

Is there a shorthand trick to avoid repeating the variable assignment? For example, is there a function such that:

```
def pipeline(x, function_handles):
    ....
    for f in function_handles:
        x.apply(f) #in place
return x
```

or

```
def pipeline(x, expression):
    ....
    for ex in expression:
        ex(x) #in place
return x
```

Comment: `map(func, iterable)`?

Comment: The most working stuff I can think of is the tuple assignment, but I have no guarantee that you can do stuff like `x, x, x = e, f(x), g(x)`, being `e` an expression, and `f` and `g` arbitrary functions.

Comment: Did you mean for `my_ordered_dict.items()` to be replaced by `x.items()` in the dictionary paragraph?

Comment: Is it really the *variable assignment* that you're worried about repeating in the second example? Not the 3 highly-repetitive dict comprehensions?

Comment: @cricket_007 Great!

Comment: @AustinHastings Fixed

Comment: @user2357112 Yes. However, a different approach would be to reduce the statement to a one-liner in a loop and simply iterate through a collection of functions. I think that phrasing the question with an emphasis on assignment seemed to encourage more Pythonic thinking.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli `x, x, x` could be reduced to `n=3; tuple(n*[x])`. However, tuples are immutable, so call by reference is not possible. But if we try `[x, x, x] = [sqrt(x), sqrt(x), sqrt(x)]` (with or without brackets) we get `sqrt(x)` and not `sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(x)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `operator` module there is the [`operator.methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) function. It works like `itemgetter`, which is the one you are most likely to have already seen: given a *name,* the return value of `methodcaller` is partial function that calls the named method of its argument.

That is, given:

```
x = SomeObjectType()
f = operator.methodcaller('amethod', 'arg1', arg2=100)
f(x)
```

Is the same as saying:

```
x = SomeObjectType()
x.amethod('arg1', arg2=100)
```

You could use this along with simple `lambda` expressions and/or [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) or `partial_method` to construct a list of functions/methods to be applied. Then, as @cricket_007 suggested, you could use or write code to automatically apply them.

Also of note is `functools.reduce`. You can write or construct a caller function, and then use `reduce` to supply it with a list of functions to call.

Here's some code to reduce a list of functions against a list of data (py3, but works in 2.7):

```
#!python3
import functools
import itertools
import operator

data = [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]

def apply(val, fn):
    print("F=",fn, "val=",val)
    return fn(val)


from functools import reduce

fns = [sorted,
        max,
        str,
    ]

print(reduce(apply, fns, data))
```